# Get variables work beyond curly brackets

Tags: php, variables

In this code I have defined variable id now if I will use `$id` outside curly brackets I will get error undefined variable for `$id`. Is there any way in which I can use variables outside brackets.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT id, email, phone, FROM members WHERE username=:username");
$check->execute(array(':username'=>$username));    
$get = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $get['id'];
$email = $get['email'];
}
 else {
 // error
}

$posts =$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=:id");
$posts->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
$row=$posts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body']; 
?>
```

Comment: First, it's probably `$_GET`, and not `$get` what you want to use. So, if you try to access `$id` after setting it to `$get['id']` value (which probably doesn't exist), you'll get undefined notice.

Comment: Define it outside curly brackets.

Comment: @AlanMachado  sorry for confusion but here I am using `$get` for `$row` it's not `$_GET`

Comment: Ok, then your problem can be something else entirely, like your `if` clause failing you. You didn't specify exactly where it is considered "outside curly brackets", is it out from `if-else` or only out from `if` (and inside `else`)?

Comment: now question is updated may it be clear now

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
 $id=""; //initialize a variable with blank value
 if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
 // query to get data
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 }
 else {
 // error
 }
?>
```

Comment: Why did you suggest OP to suppress errors with `@`? If `$_GET` index is not set or empty, there are best ways to check it rather then pretending the error/notice doesn't exist!

Comment: @AlanMachado: Agree :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
You can define your variable id like `global $id;` define immediate after php tag started .

```
    <?php
     global $id;
     if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
     // query to get data
     $id = $get['id'];
     }
     else {
     // error
     }
    ?>
```